# Spring REST API And preventing changes to auto generated properties?

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-mvc, spring-data

I am working on a REST API using Spring MVC and Spring Data.

I am exposing a few entities to with REST that have basically auto generated data (ID, Update date and create date)

```
public class Batch implements Serializable
{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "hibernate_sequence")
    private Integer id;

    @Column(name = "create_date")
    private Date createDate;

    @Column(name = "update_date")
    private Date updateDate;

    // Getters/Setters for these fields
}
```

Here are is how my controller is setup for handling the request

```
@RequestMapping(value = "recipe/{id}/batch", method = RequestMethod.POST)
@ResponseBody
public ResponseEntity<Batch> createBatch(@PathVariable Integer id, @RequestBody Batch batch)
{
    batch.setRecipeId(id);
    Batch in = batchService.createBatch(batch);

    return new ResponseEntity<Batch>(in, HttpStatus.CREATED);
}

@RequestMapping(value = "recipe/{id}/batch/{batchId}", method = RequestMethod.PUT)
@ResponseBody
public ResponseEntity<Batch> updateBatch(@PathVariable Integer id, @PathVariable Integer batchId, @RequestBody Batch batch)
{
    Batch existing = batchService.getBatch(batchId);
    batch.setId(batchId);
    batch.setRecipeId(id);
    batch.setCreateDate(existing.getCreateDate());

    Batch in = batchService.saveBatch(batch);

    return new ResponseEntity<Batch>(in, HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

Then finally the batch service
   public Batch createBatch(Batch batch)
    {
        Batch saved = batchRepository.save(batch);
        return saved;
    }

```
public Batch saveBatch(Batch batch)
{
    return batchRepository.save(batch);
}
```

How best would I go about preventing these fields from being updated when fed into the service that handles it? Should I just manually copy them in the service from the version that was PUT/POST from REST or is there a better way to filter out data for these fields from the API. Manually copying them also sounds very tedious when I have roughly 15 different resources.

I still want them to be displayed when a user does a GET on the resource, i just don't want any values they supply but I can't really find a good example of how to manage this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should mark the fields like create_date or id as "non-updateable" which avoids overwriting existing values

```
    @Column(name = "create_date", insertable = true, updatable = false)
```

Comment: This works great for the update side of things, but allows people to enter id's instead of auto generated ones, which looks like something I will just handle manually.

Answer (score 0):

In your code, **you save new batch, instead of merging existing one**, this is the source of the problem with generated ID, basically, **what you should do is update relevant fields of related existing Entity, and save updated existing entity**, that would merge your changes.

It's ugly, but I have not seen anything more elegant yet.